# OSB xquery: subtract hours to an date

Tags: xquery, osb

Can somebody tell me how to subtract hours to a datetime in OSB/Xquery?

For example current date minus 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function available in XQuery called "subtract-dayTimeDurations" 
E.g. :
subtract-dayTimeDurations(  dayTimeDuration     $srcval1,dayTimeDuration $srcval2)

Result will be returned as below:
op:subtract-dayTimeDurations(xf:dayTimeDuration("P2DT12H"), xf:dayTimeDuration("P1DT10H30M")) returns a dayTimeDuration value corresponding to 1 day and 1.5 hours.

From the result you can pick your required input.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore combination of dayTimeDuration() with duration(). This way it's flexible.

here is how i would add 5 days in 2015-01-01

let $date := string(xs:date("2015-01-01") + xdt:dayTimeDuration(xs:duration(concat('P',abs(5),'D'))))